# Etymology/meaning of (Mount) Kyllene

Tags: etymology, greek

My unabridged Liddell/Scott does not have any indication of what the name of the Greek Mount "Kyllene" means.  Robert Graves in "The Greek Myths" says it means "Twisted Queen."  I have seen where he can be off in his interpretation of names, plus that just sounds like an odd name for the mountain.  Does someone have a reliable source for the meaning of "Kyllene"?

Comment: I don't know where the name comes from, but Kyllẽnē was also the name of a nymph who lived at that mountain. That could explain Graves' translation.

Comment: (*Kyllós* means "deformed", from *(s)kel- "bend", but I'm not sure how one would get "queen" from -ēnē. Or of any other source backing this up.)

Comment: Graves was a novelist, not a linguist.

Comment: The meaning twisted queen is rather wild imagination. Draconis etymology seems correct to me.

Comment: Thank you, Draconis and others.  I came across kullos as a description of Hefaistos' deformed legs ("bandy-legged"), but I also came across kulle', meaning "a cup, any hollow:  the palm of the hand," and remembered that Hermes' epithet, "Kullenios," has associations with smithing.  Do you think there might be an ancient, though infrequent, association between Hermes' magical/smithing qualities?  The mountain was mythically named after Kullenos, a daktul ("finger," associated with magical and mystical smithing gods) of Samothrake' and elsewhere.

Comment: Please phrase your question in the form of a question.

Answer (score 3):

OK Pausanias (Paus. 8.17.1) gives it to:

> After the grave of Aepytus you come to the highest mountain in Arcadia, Cyllene, on the top of which is a dilapidated temple of Cyllenian Hermes. It is clear that Cyllen, the son of Elatus, gave the mountain its name and the god his surname. ( δῆλα δέ ἐστιν ἀπὸ Κυλλῆνος τοῦ Ἐλάτου τῷ τε ὄρει τὸ ὄνομα καὶ ἡ ἐπίκλησις γεγενημένη τῷ θεῷ.)

I know little about this gentleman (Κυλλήν, the above being apparently his only claim to fame), but Beekes  gives

> κυλλός [adj.] 'deformed, crippled, crooked', of hands, feet, etc. (lA).  ... .ETYM Probably connected with κελλόν:  στρεβλόν, πλάγιον  'twisted, athwart' (H.)...  In view of its semantics and problematic lE etymology, the word may as well be Pre-Greek (cf. Fur.: 35455).

Further see [WP](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%BA%CF%85%CE%BB%CE%BB%CF%8C%CF%82).

Α Pre-Greek placename is plausible, given their plethora in the area, but if you have [seen](https://www.flickr.com/photos/dandiffendale/3842065784) the crooked mountain, you cannot escape the evident inference. (Where Graves' queen came from one should not have a clue.)